# Ansible Playbook to copy a file to a remote host - Permission denied - How to send credentials?

Tags: copy, ansible, transfer, permission-denied

I'm trying to copy a file, local, to a remote host using a simple Ansible playbook:

```
    ---
   - name: Transfer file to remote host device
     hosts: remotehost
     connection: local

     tasks:
          - name: Send file to remote host
            copy:
              src: /home/plc/cert.pfx
              dest: /root/certificates
```

But I'm getting permission denied. What's the User/Password that's being used when trying to send the file to the remote host? Can I specify it?

Error I'm getting as follow:

> fatal: [remotehost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Failed to get information on remote file (/root/certificates): Permission denied"}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the destination path is `/root/certificates`, you must either:

- connect as `root` (not recommended), or
- use privilege escalation with `become: true`.

  Your connecting account must be configured to be able to do so — all that is [well documented](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/become.html), so learn and apply.

---

Besides, you have an unnecessary `connection: local` in your play definition which prevents from connecting to the target server. Remove it.

Considering that, maybe you should start with [Getting Started](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/intro_getting_started.html) chapter of Ansible documentation.